# Can I change an application status in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect

I have an application in which there are 9 in app purchases. I have created them and all are ready to submit, but unfortunately I have given ready to upload binary with out selecting the in app purchase items. Now the apps' state is **Waiting for Upload**, but i forgot to select the in app purchases. Is there any way I can resubmit the app again? Can anybody help me?

Comment: thanks to all...saved my life ..thank u all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit(Upload) the binary of your App using **Application Loader** or through Xcode. The status would change to **Waiting For Review**.

Then from iTunes Home Page, click **Manage Your Applications -> Select your App(you just uploaded) -> View Details -> Binary Details -> Reject This Binary**

Following this would allow you to submit the in App Purchases along with the App for review

Answer (score 2):

Simply reject your binary and submit a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Submit any binary and then reject it.  That will allow you to go in and add the IAP's.  Then submit your app.